# How much weight can a bald eagle carry?

Tags: birds, bald-eagles

Just recently, a [photographer was watching](http://www.foxnews.com/science/2018/05/22/eagle-snatches-fox-holding-rabbit-in-mouth-in-dramatic-images.html) some foxes hunt rabbits. One of the foxes caught a rabbit when a bald eagle swooped down grabbed the rabbit and pulled both rabbit and fox into the air. The fox let go and the eagle took the rabbit..

That brings up the question of **how much weight can a bald eagle carry?**

Comment: African or Indian Bald Eagle? :=)

Comment: As much as it wants, who am I to argue? :) (Charlie's not getting much help just yet, I'm afraid.)

Comment: See [Eagles filmed hunting reindeer](http://news.bbc.co.uk/earth/hi/earth_news/newsid_8314000/8314558.stm) I found that when writting an answer to [Will owls attack small dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/will-owls-attack-small-dogs/8129#8129)

Comment: @DJClayworth Do you mean African or European?

Comment: @Acccumulation D'oh. Yes I do.

Comment: :: @DJClayworth is thrown off the cliff ::

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Alaskan Fish And Game](http://www.adfg.alaska.gov/index.cfm?adfg=wildlifenews.view_article&articles_id=343) department,

> "The wings of an eagle need to support the eight to 12-pound bird as
>   well as whatever the bird is carrying, and best estimates put the
>   lifting power of an eagle at four or five pounds. ..."

But as the article continues,

> "Lift is dependent not only on wing size, but on airspeed. The faster
>   a bird (or plane) is flying, the greater the lift potential. An eagle
>   that lands on the beach to grab a fish, and then takes off again, is
>   limited to a smaller load than an eagle that swoops down at 20 or 30
>   miles an hour and snatches up a fish. That momentum and speed gives
>   the bird the ability to carry more weight."

This may or may not explain [Amazing Bird Records](https://www.trails.com/arts/amazing-bird-records.aspx) for:

> *greatest weight-carrying capacity*: bald eagle lifting a 6.8 kg (15 lb)
>   mule deer

Comment: Lands on the beach to grab a fish? Like one that's just laying there? I'm having trouble understanding what they're thinking of.

Comment: Momentum would help with the force required to accelerate the object   off the ground. However after that it would still need to have enough lift to carry on carrying - in this instance the fox letting go would help!

Comment: @AzorAhai it's a hypothetical situation to illustrate the physics; it doesn't have to be 100% plausible...

Comment: @Walt Still, a weird example to pick.

Comment: @AzorAhai You may want to look up salmon spawning.  Naturally they beach and die.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmon_run

Comment: @paparazzo They left that out of *The Magic School Bus*.

Comment: @AzorAhai  Hopefully the series will be cancelled for that lapse.

Comment: @AzorAhai, Bald Eagles are also scavengers.  If there is an easy meal available, they are more than happy to save the energy and eat something already dead.  They don't limit their scavenging to fish either.